# MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onPageStarted(String,Bitmap) in Listener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show a html file with [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) component. But the problem is, it shows an error for the line

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {
```

The error says,

> Error:(18, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method onPageStarted(String,Bitmap) in Listener

This is my **MainActivity.java** file.

```
package com.test.test3;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {
    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setListener(this, this);
        mWebView.setGeolocationEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setMixedContentAllowed(true);
        mWebView.setCookiesEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);

        mWebView.addHttpHeader("X-Requested-With", "");
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: click on the error, then press `ALT+ENTER`, then `ENTER.`

Comment: @ZUNJAE, you saved my day. Couldn't be much easier. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement an interface by class and this class isn't abstract, you have to override all interface methods.

Your `MainActivity` implements [this interface](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/master/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L64):

```
public interface Listener {
        void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon);
        void onPageFinished(String url);
        void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl);
        void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent);
        void onExternalPageRequest(String url);
    }
```

But doesn't override it's methods.

You need to override all [`AdvancedWebView.Listener`](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/master/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L64) methods: `onPageStarted`, `onPageFinished`, `onPageError`, `onDownloadRequested`, `onExternalPageRequest`.

Comment: "If you implement an interface by class and this class isn't abstract, you should override all interface methods." I would say : **you have to**

Comment: @davidxxx okay, thanks. My english isn't fluent yet :(

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The problem has been solved. Cheers.

Comment: @Ashonko ZUNJAE's comment helps you to simply solve the effects of problem, and I tried to help you resolve the reasons :) If answer satisfies you, please mark it as correct by check mark. Thanks :)